# Split a string into an array according to keywords in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string

What I have is a long string that I extracted from an uploaded file, I am trying to split this string according to keywords, I know there are many answers here about splitting and exploding a string but none of them gave me a clue on how to solve my problem since I am not relying on white spaces or a specific number of characters, the only factor I have is the occurrences of certain keywords, here is what I tried:

```
    $text = readMyFile('filename.txt');
    //Now $text contains a very long unformatted text but there are keywords
    $keyword = 'ADDRESS:'; //there is only one occurrence of ADDRESS:
    $address = explode($keyword, $text);

    print_r($address); //$address[1] contains all text after the keyword ADDRESS:
```

but I have other keywords to search for, and now I have an array of two elements, all text before and after the keyword, how is it possible to repeat this procedure over and over to extract all text in between keywords, for example in between 'ADDRESS:' and 'JOB TITLE' so that I get the full address from the original document in one element of an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably use [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/preg_match_all) for this:

```
$keywords = ['ADDRESS', 'JOB TITLE'];
$pattern = sprintf('/(?:%s):(.*?)/', join('|', array_map(function($keyword) {
    return preg_quote($keyword, '/');
}, $keywords)));

preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $matches);
```

*The text that comes before the first keyword is skipped.*